# Open activity after closing another activity

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, dialogfragment

I'm having an issue with my android game and I've searched for help for two days and I couldn't find the answer. So it goes like this, I have an activity and a dialogfragment. The activity has in-app purchases (IabHelper class, etc).

The dialogfragment is called when the level is finished. When the event dismiss is called by the dialogfragment, it closes the activity and re start the exact same activity but with other level (there is a switch in the onCreate that changes the layout depending the level). The thing is, when I complete a level, and the new appears, if I try to buy something, it crashes because the IabHelper object is null:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.carvalina.footballsmart.util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(android.app.Activity, java.lang.String, int, com.carvalina.footballsmart.util.IabHelper$OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

My dialogfragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_win, container, false);
    //getDialog().setTitle("");
    Button dismiss = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
    dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int nivelActual = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("nivel");
            abrirNivel(nivelActual+1);
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
protected void abrirNivel(int nivel){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Nivel.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("nivel", nivel);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    getActivity().finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In the onDestroy method of my activity, the IabHelper object is cleared BUT, when I debugged the app I found out that, the new activity is created even if the onDestroy method is not finished. Is there any way to wait until the first activity is closed and then open the new one?

Comment: you could use a finish() to close and end the first application

Comment: @MNM you mean when I call the dialogfragment, I should finish it there? I've tried that, and its the same.

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isDestroyed%28%29

Comment: @MNM I have two issues, first I'm using 16 as minimum API level, and second, don't know how to make the "wait until isDestroyed is true and then do this", because if I use if statement it will never create the second activity

Comment: Then go with onDestroy() that may do it.

Comment: you should not rely on a dialogfragment to create and stop activities all the time to begin with

Comment: The timing of `onDestroy()` or even the fact that it will be called is not guaranteed. Why not clear the `iabHelper` in `onStop()`? Or, you can solve this issue by setting your activity's `launchMode` to `singleTop`. This way you can have your level logic in `onNewIntent()` rather than in `onCreate()` and potentially avoid the overhead of creating new instance every time you go to the next level.

Comment: @liminal I've changed the way I go through levels within a second activity that goes between the completed one and the new one. I think this is the best way to make it, but thanks anyway. Are you familiarized with IabHelper and in-app purchases? I have another question but it doesn't goes with this post (maybe I can email you if you dont bother?)